# SQL developer on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, rpm

I am trying to install Oracle SQL Developer onto a Linux server via the Windows 8.1 operating system. I am downloading the packages from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

I am then installing the Linux RPM package from that site.

I am then moving it from the Windows 8.1 operating system (that it was downloaded onto) onto the Linux server (via WinSCP).

I am then opening up the Linux server on Putty and attempting to install the SQL Developer by using the following command:

```
rpm -Uvh sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm
```

I am then recieving this error:

```
   rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages,
   use Alien instead!
   rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
   error: Failed dependencies:
       /bin/sh is needed by sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this issue, I have searched Google and no useful results have popped up.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on the [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)/[Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) sites instead.

Comment: Presumably `/bin/sh` does exist on your Linux box? I'm not sure what the relevance of Windows is here - you seem to just be using it to stage the .rpm file you downloaded, or are you wondering if that has corrupted it somehow? The error isn't suggesting that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use RPM package management on Ubuntu and Ubuntu is asking you to use Alien instead. You can install Alien and use it as shown below.

On your Ubuntu machine execute the following line.

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Then once installed you should try this to install your RPM package.

```
sudo alien -i sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm
```

If that doesn't work you can repackage the RPM into a Debian package as follows and then install the Deb Package like this.

```
sudo alien sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm
sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.deb
```

Hope that helps,
Pat